# WebSocket: client does not response to server

Tags: php, websocket

I am new to websocket.
I have made a simple websocket implementation on PHP. Handshaking works fine, and the connection is definitely on, since my server can get messages from client.

But, once I try to send message back to client, the client does not response at all.

Here is the code that mask messages and send it back to client.

```
function myProcess($user,$buffer)
{
//$buffer=unwrap($buffer);
console("Request Caught.");
console("Content Length: ".strlen($buffer));
console("Content: ".unmask($buffer));
console("First 8 bits: ".ord($buffer[0]));
console("Opcode: ".opcode($buffer,true));
//console("Full Text: ".$buffer);
//socket_write($user->socket,mask(unmask($buffer)));
console("Masking: ");
$tmp=unmask($buffer);
console($tmp);
$masked=mask($tmp);
opcode($masked);
for($i=0;$i<strlen($masked);$i++)
{
    console($i.": ".ord($masked[$i]));
}
console("length: ".strlen($masked));
console("Sending Response: ");
console(socket_write($user->socket,$masked,strlen($masked)));
}


function mask($text)
{
    $first8bit=0x81;
    $header;
    console("mask: payload length:".strlen($text));
    if(strlen($text)<=125)
    {
        $header=pack("CC",$first8bit,strlen($text));
    }
    else if(strlen($text)<65536)
    {
        $header=pack("CCS",$first8bit,126,strlen($text));
    }
    else
    {
        $header=pack("CCN",$first8bit,127,strlen($text));
    }
    return $header.$text;
}
```

If the client send "hi" to server, server is going to simply reply "hi". And the captured packets with wireshark is 81 02 68 69. It seems the bits on the wire is just as the protocol says. If server trys to send a longer string, for example "hi from server", the client response with an error: undefined.

Can anyone help? Thanks a lot.

This is the code of server:

```
while(true){
  $changed = $sockets;
  socket_select($changed,$write=NULL,$except=NULL,NULL);
  foreach($changed as $socket){
    if($socket==$master){
        console("Master Socket Changed.");
      $client=socket_accept($master);
      if($client<0){ console("socket_accept() failed"); continue; }
      else{ connect($client); }
    }
    else{
        console($socket." Socket Changed.");
        $str=socket_read($socket,2048);
        $user=getuserbysocket($socket);
        if(strlen($str)==0) disconnect($socket);
        else if(!$user->handshake){ dohandshake($user,$str); }
        else
        {
            myProcess($socket,$str);
        }
        console("Comunication Ends Here.");
    }
  }
}
```

This is the calculation of accept section:

```
function calc_accept($key)
{
    $tmp=$key."258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
    $tmp=sha1($tmp,true);
    //console($tmp);
    $tmp=base64_encode($tmp);
    //console($tmp);
    return $tmp;
}
```

This does the handshake:

```
function dohandshake($user,$buffer){
  console("\nRequesting handshake...");
  console($buffer);
  list($resource,$host,$origin,$strkey,$data) = getheaders($buffer);
  console("Handshaking...");
  $upgrade="HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n".
                    "Upgrade: websocket\r\n".
                    "Connection: Upgrade\r\n".
                    "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: ".calc_accept($strkey)."\r\n\r\n";
  socket_write($user->socket,$upgrade.chr(0),strlen($upgrade.chr(0)));
  $user->handshake=true;
  console($upgrade);
  console("Done handshaking...");
  return true;
}
```

These 2 function gets the handshake of client and get user object by a socket:

```
function getheaders($req){
  $r=$h=$o=null;
  if(preg_match("/GET (.*) HTTP/"   ,$req,$match)){ $r=$match[1]; }
  if(preg_match("/Host: (.*)\r\n/"  ,$req,$match)){ $h=$match[1]; }
  if(preg_match("/Origin: (.*)\r\n/",$req,$match)){ $o=$match[1]; }
  if(preg_match("/Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)\r\n/",$req,$match)){ $key=$match[1]; }
  if(preg_match("/\r\n(.*?)\$/",$req,$match)){ $data=$match[1]; }
  return array($r,$h,$o,$key,$data);
}

function getuserbysocket($socket){
  global $users;
  $found=null;
  foreach($users as $user){
    if($user->socket==$socket){ $found=$user; break; }
  }
  return $found;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are writing to the client on the correct socket? Sending messages to the client is separate the socket from receiving them.

Comment: Yes, I accept the newly incoming socket and saved it to an User object for later use. I think giving error on client when sending a longer string shows that the client gets the bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format string for `pack` looks wrong for messages between 126 and 65536 bytes.  Can you try changing

> "CCS" - unsigned short (always 16 bit, machine byte order)

to

> "CCn" - unsigned short (16-bit) in "network" (big-endian) order

Comment: I have changed it, but that does not help...and the length of "hi" is 2, definitely the if statement of >125 && <=65526 will not be reached.

Comment: I thought your question said that sending "hi" worked but sending (unspecified) longer messages failed?  Does sending "hi" also fail?

Comment: My situation is that sending "hi" back to client, the client-side does not give any response, sending "hi from server", client-side will give error: undefined. More specifically, sending any frame that is shorter than 6 bytes, client will not response, but sending any frame longer that 6 bytes, client will give error message.

Comment: Thanks, I understand.  Are you sure you don't send any data from any code not included in your question?  Say additional data at the end of the handshake.  It might be worth posting more code to double check this.

Comment: Hi, I have post almost all my code in this post. I am getting mad about this strange problem. IF YOU CAN, PLEASE HELP, THANKS A LOT!!

Comment: Thanks.  I'm afraid I can't see anything wrong with your code.  You could try using wireshark to make absolutely sure that the data going over the wire precisely matches what is shown in your code/logging here.

Comment: Thank god, you are right, I re-checked my code, it is just as you say, the bytes I am sending is not correct. chr(0) of socket_write($user->socket,$upgrade.chr(0),strlen($upgrade.chr(0))) in handshake function breaks all the staff. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

To anyone whom is struggling on the strange problem, this is the answer:

DELETE chr(0) of socket_write($user->socket,$upgrade.chr(0),strlen($upgrade.chr(0))) from handshake function.

I will still mark simnoc's answer as correct one, because he inspired me. Thanks